# How can I strip a leading zero from a number in custom fields? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an EAN code in a custom field, but unfortunately it has more then 13 characters because there are always leading zeros in it.

Example:
04055432153691 -> 4055432153691

Is there a way to strip this zero from the field so there are 13 characters?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Karolin

Comment: Can you share the code? At least, what's the name of this custom field?

Comment: just use : $str = substr($custom_field, 1);

Comment: Actually I am importing some data from a feed with WP All import. The xml file is imported with Xpath values.

The custom field is like that:

Name -> Value
EAN -> {Details[1]/EAN[1]}

When I do the import I can define the php function to execute while the import runs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the substr() function of the PHP. By which you can remove the leading 0,

$var =  substr($num, 1);

See this for better knowledge. http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/substr.php